# RadDocking Stutter

Tags: wpf, telerik, raddocking

Ok my application using Devexpress 11, its old and I'm thinking to switch to Telerik instead, I download the WPF demo check all necessary component until I stumbled onto RadDocking from telerik. and my first impression was slow/jittery/stutter animation.

My question is this is normal even when deploying in full application? or it will be smoother than when in demo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well since no help coming :( I just go ahead and try the trial my impression what just exactly like in demo. seriously even when there's nothing on screen just 1 pinned document it looks strange pinning and unpin have like blip animation whats worse is when moving floating document the movement feel strange it feel like animation jump around like skipping pixel. Though there's a lot of animation, fell unnecessary thou.

Anyway, I heard about Telerik a lot so I kind of excited turn I was wrong when it come to performance, even for most basic thing makes me wonder how thing will be when project got big enough.